# Is it possible to specify function as parameter's default value?

Tags: scala

Let's say that I have a function as below:

```
def func(x: Int)(f: Int => Boolean) = f(x)
```

Is it possible to define a default value for the function?

```
def func(x: Int)(f: Int => Boolean = defaultFunc) = f(x)
```

Where defaultFunc is a function that goes from Int to Boolean. I will anyways try this out by myself, but just thought of posting it here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, as you could find out by yourself using REPL or [scalafiddle](http://scalafiddle.net/console):

```
def defaultFunc(x: Int): Boolean = ???
// defaultFunc: (x: Int)Boolean

def func(x: Int)(f: Int => Boolean = defaultFunc) = f(x)
// func: (x: Int)(f: Int => Boolean)Boolean
```

Comment: Indeed, surely doing that in a repl takes less time than asking an SO!!